# Redis working with ~4k max file descriptors

Tags: java, redis, redis-cluster, redisson

I've seen multiple questions/answers on how to increase the max file descriptors so Redis won't complain about it but my question is different and I don't seem to find an answer:

Trying to use it, in a clustered setup, with (for example) ~4k maxclients either from explicit config or as it fallbacks to such value based on system's max file descriptors is simply a call for trouble, was 10k default chosen for a reason?

We actually had issues because no more connections could be opened and trying to figure out if we need to continue our investigation on the dev team side or we should simply consider increasing max file descriptors since we need to go through our infra team for that and they are very sceptic we need more than we already have...